# Why cant i output HTML code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to output HTML on my webpages by doing

```
  <p>
    @Server.HtmlEncode(elem.Text.ToString().Replace("[BR]", "<br />"));
  </p>
```

`[BR]` is my coded `<br />` since i wont/cant save html directly. However, the problem is that when i use the @Server.HtmlEncode i get this output:

```
one little&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;test!;
```

Without the encoding also looks wrong, it then output `<br />`'s in plaintext :(

Does anyone have a clue how to make it encode/output correctly?

Comment: HtmlEncode encodes text to be suitable for transmission in html. That is, `<,>` aren't valid xml, so they get encoded. I don't know asp.net, but you're getting exactly what you're telling the code to give you.

Comment: What does *correctly* means? Provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are double HTML encoding. `@` already performs an Html encode. Try:

```
@elem.Text.ToString().Replace("[BR]", "<br />")
```

or:

```
@(new HtmlString(elem.Text.ToString().Replace("[BR]", "<br />")))
```

or:

```
@Html.Raw(elem.Text.ToString().Replace("[BR]", "<br />"))
```

Comment: `Raw`!  Doh, never knew about it!  Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

The word `Encode` in `HtmlEncode` means it translates raw html to it's encoded output, ie what you are seeing.  If you want raw html, then you do `Response.Write()` or, since it looks like you're using Razor, `@Html.Raw()`.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlEncode escapes special characters like < >. Use Html.Raw instead of if.